# if user forgot the password, how can the use fill email then password_hash password send password to user email?

Tags: php, mysql

If the user forgot the password, how can the use of fill email then password_hash password send the password to user email?

when the user register, I use this method to hash the password.

```
$password1 = $_POST['password'];
$password1 = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

So, when the user forgot the password, how can send a real password to the user Email?

my code

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserEmail ='".$email."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mail($email, "Your account password is ".$row['']."test", "test@example.com" );
    $result['success'] = "1";
    $result['message'] = "success";
    echo json_encode($result ,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You can't reverse it, that's the whole point of hashing password. You should ask users to reset their password

Comment: so, just reset password ?

Comment: @catcon is correct. You need to create a `forgot/reset` password flow so your user can create a new password. It's the safe way to do this.

Comment: @Stanley: yes, and you should not consider any solution to send password over email, it's considered a bad practice, see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure)

Comment: @Stanley what would be the point in hashing the password in the first place if anyone could reverse the hash and see the plain text password? The password hash is meant to protect against database breaches. Think about if someone got access to google's databases and copied everyone's passwords.